# Is there a way to set the expiration date of a BigQuery table to "None" using the Python client library?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

The BigQuery table created before my billing has been set to expire.

I don't want the tables to be automatically deleted, so I'm looking for a way to set the expiration date of these tables to "None".

However, I have more than 100 tables, so I am looking for a convenient way to do this. (Therefore, I'm not looking for a way to set them one by one in the console.)

The sample code I wrote is as follows

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set dataset_id to the ID of the dataset that contains
#                  the tables you are listing.
dataset_id = 'my_project_name.analytics_00000000'
expiration = None

tables = client.list_tables(dataset_id)  # Make an API request.
for table in tables:
    table.expires = expiration
    table = client.update_table(table, ["expires"])
```

And here's the error message I got.

```
can't set attribute
  File "set_expires_to_none.py", line 13, in <module>
    table.expires = expiration
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Set a future date of 2999-12-31.if this works

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because the `list_tables` doesn't actually return a table object it returns a `A read-only table resource from a list operation.` see documentation here: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableListItem.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableListItem

try the following instead:

```
tables = client.list_tables('so_test')
for table in tables:
    table = client.get_table(table)
    table.expires = None
    table = client.update_table(table, ["expires"])
    print(table.table_id)
    print(table.expires)
```